# Is it possible to use outlook office 365's agenda in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

can I use the office 365 agenda in sharepoint online?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve and how your end results should be?

Comment: I need the native sharepoint calendar online to have Outlook calendar features and their appearance.

Comment: Did you ever try SharePoint Out of the box calendar?

Comment: Not yet, how can I use it?

Comment: I have posted an answer with complete details which helps your to get started.

Comment: Note that Sharepoint calendar will not be able to send invites like outlook does.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, there is an out of the box calendar app which can be used to create an Organization, team or personal calendars.

As you are new to this app you can go through below videos for better understanding.

[How to create a calendar in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-your-own-SharePoint-calendar-c725a546-31e9-4096-a54d-ac7c8eca41ac)

[How to create a shared Calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-a-shared-calendar-in-Office-365-61b96006-70e2-4535-a34f-ee4fc772f798?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)